# must an irreducible group of matrices span the matrix algebra

Tags: matrices, representation-theory

let $G\subseteq \text{U}_n(\mathbf{C})$ be a matrix subgroup for which the representation of $G$ on $\mathbf{C}^n$ is irreducible.

Question 1. is it true that $\text{span}_{\mathbf{C}}G=\mathbf{C}^{n\times n}$ ? what if we assume only $G\subseteq \text{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ ?

Question 2. if $\text{trace}(g)$ takes only finitely many values, can we bound $|G|$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you know Burnside's Theorem?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know Burnside's theorem

Answer (score 1):

Questions 1. Yes and yes. The result is called the "density theorem". We can show that if $A$ is a sub-algebra of $M_n(\mathbb C)$, and the representation of $A$ on $\mathbb C^n$ is irreducible, then $A=M_n(\mathbb C)$. See e.g. Theorem 3.2.2 in [Introduction to Representation Theory](https://klein.mit.edu/%7Eetingof/reprbook.pdf).

Question 2. Not really. Any group $G$ has a trivial representation that's also irreducible, and this representation cannot be used to bound $|G|$.

Comment: Thank you. can you please explain what you mean by "any group has a trivial representation that's also irreducible"

Comment: Given $G$, take the representation $\rho:G\rightarrow U_1(\mathbb C)$, $\rho(g)=1, \forall g\in G$. This $\rho$ is irreducible, and trace$(g)$ takes only finitely many values, but this rep tells nothing about $|G|$.